# jQuery/AJAX: each, if, post, .html: Runs but randomly deletes data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a PHP page, with FedEx & UPS tracking numbers in a MySQL database echoing into ID's of DIVs with the class "trackingnumber". My JS each's through those divs and grabs the ID to then post to a PHP page that polls Fedex/UPS and echos the result from them. That works great, except for one thing. It randomly deletes the data after it's loaded it. So the data will flash on the screen for a second, and then disappear. It's random too, which just baffles me. Check out this [Video demonstrating the issue (.mov)](http://cameronconner.name/ISUHD2.mov) to get a better understanding.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Dislay some text indicating that we're getting status
    if ($("[id!='']")) {
        $("div.trackingnumber").html("working...");
    };
    //Begin getting status
    $('div.trackingnumber').each(function(index){
        var v2 = $(this).attr("id");
        //If it's FedEx, post to the FedEx script.
        if ($("[id!='1z'], [id!='1Z']")) {
            $.post("inc/fedex.php", { v: v2 }, function(data){
                $("#" + v2).html(data);
            });
        };
        //If it's UPS, post to the ups script.
        if ($("[id^='1z'], [id^='1Z']")) {
            $.post("inc/ups.php", { v: v2 }, function(data){
                $("#" + v2).html(data);
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Relevant HTML (after PHP has parsed it):

```
<td scope='col' width='100px'>
        <div class='trackingnumber' id='1ZX799380311650886'></div>
</td>
```

Any ideas? I'm new to jQuery (and JS in general)... I've got no idea why this is doing what it is. It looks like all my code is valid (the only errors in FireBug or Safari's web inspector are when it hits a div without any data in the class)... I've been battling this for about a day now, finally getting it to this point... Really hoping someone will be able to help me out!

Comment: By just looking at your code, I don't see any logical errors. I would suggest you to do: console.log($(this)); inside the loop to ensure the matched elements are what you want.

Comment: Check the post requests in firebug to make sure they're returning the correct data and that the right number of requests are being fired.

Comment: munch is right. Looking at the "Net" tab in Firebug would have clued you in to the problem. Hopefully my answer (below) is the correct solution. Good job on the question though; it was clear, concise and even included video evidence! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood how jQuery works; your `if` statements don't make sense at all.

`$("[id!='']")` will *always* return a jQuery object which, due to JavaScript's automatic type coercion, will *always* evaluate to `true`. In other words `$("[id!='']") == true` no matter what your HTML looks like. The same applies for the rest of your `if` statements.

Because of this mistake your code retrieves *both* the results of the UPS and FedEx scripts *every time*. Since the AJAX calls are asynchronous your results may appear in different orders thus causing an apparently random clearing of the data (when the empty data is returned *after* the correct data).

This is how I assume you intended your code to behave:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Select all of the tracking numbers on the page
  $(".trackingnumber").
    // Display some text in each, indicating that we're getting status
    text("working...").
    // Begin getting status for each tracking number.
    each(function () {
      var trackingNumber = this.id;

      // Use the fedex script by default ...
      var script = "fedex";

      if (trackingNumber.match(/^1z/i)) {
        // ... unless it's a UPS tracking number.
        script = "ups";
      }

      $.post("inc/" + script + ".php", { v: trackingNumber }, function(data){
          $("#" + trackingNumber).html(data);
      });
    });
});
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsbin.com/iyeci (editable via http://jsbin.com/iyeci/edit)

Don't hesitate to ask if you need more help understanding the code.

Comment: Excellent! I was using the if ['id^'blah'] due to reading that it was more efficient than the match, and was figuring that wasn't the issue (despite the working... one wasn't correctly not showing when there wasn't any tracking number in the id) since it was deleting the data randomly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've added:
if (trackingNumber.length !=0) {
    $(this).text("working...");
};

To the code so that "working..." only displays when there actually is something to work on.

Just for future reference. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you want to exclude `trackingnumber`s that don't have an `id`, use `$(".trackingnumber[id!='']")` instead of `$(".trackingnumber")`. Adding that `if` statement won't prevent the unnecessary AJAX request.